# If select returns 0 rows insert data

Tags: ios, database, html, web-sql

I currently have a transaction that attempts to insert data into a table. If the data is already in the table a constraint failed error is raised and a select is run to get the ID.

```
t2.executeSql('INSERT INTO books (book) VALUES (?);',
  [record],
  function (t2, r) {        // SQL_successfulCallback
    record = r.insertId;
  },
  function (t2, err) {      // SQL_errorCallback
    if (err.message !== 'constraint failed') { // insert failed because of other
                                               // reason - fail transaction
      console.log('Insert SQL error ' + err.code + ' - ' + err.message + '.');
      return true;
    } else { // insert failed because data was already in the table
      t2.executeSql('SELECT bookID FROM books WHERE book=?',
        [record],
        function (t, r) {   // SQL_successfulCallback
          record = r.rows.item(0).classificationID;
        },
        function (t, err) { // SQL_errorCallback
          console.log('Lookup SQL error ' + err.code + ' - ' + err.message + '.');
          return true;
        }
      );
      return false;
    }
  }
);
```

I want to speed the transaction up so I thought I would see if the data was in the table first. If it isn't then insert it...

```
t2.executeSql('SELECT bookID FROM books WHERE book=?',
  [record],
  function (t2, r) {          // SQL_successfulCallback
    if (r.rows.length !== 0) {
      record = r.rows.item(0).bookID;
    } else {
      t2.executeSql('INSERT INTO books (book) VALUES (?);',
        [record],
        function(t2, r){      // SQL_successfulCallbac
          record = r.insertId;
        },
        function (t2, err) {  // SQL_errorCallback
          if (err.message !== 'constraint failed') { // insert failed because of other
                                                     // reason - fail transaction
            console.log('Insert SQL error ' + err.code + ' - ' + err.message + '.');
            return true;
          } else { // insert failed because data was already in the table
            return false;
          }
        }
      );
    }
  },
  function (t, err) {         // SQL_errorCallback
    console.log('Lookup SQL error ' + err.code + ' - ' + err.message + '.');
    return true;
  }
);
```

...but it doesn't work. This transaction runs all the selects then does the inserts. How can I make the second method work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the transaction is queuing the request.  So your queue will look like this

Select 1

Select 2

Select 3

Then when you commit your transaction looks like this after the first call.

Select 2

Select 3

Insert 1

Insert 2

Insert 3

This is happening because the the functions to call the inserts are exected after the select is ran and this doesn't happen until the transaction commits but the selects have already be registered.

In order to get it to be

select1

insert1

select2

insert2

I would create a separate transaction for each select statement.

Comment: **DON'T DO METHOD 2!** Method 1 takes 22 seconds with 28,439 records. Method 2 with the transaction wrapper that Michael suggested takes _34_ seconds for the same number of records!

Comment: How may records are you inserting at once and how are you getting the data to input.  I was assuming that users were just entering a couple records at a time is this the case or are you inserting 28,439 records at once?

Comment: The data is coming from JSON files.Instead of looking then inserting, I'm building arrays in memory to hold unique values for the tables then using that smaller array to do the inserts.